# Logging out/back in sometimes freezes after login to blank wallpaper

Tags: 11.04, boot, ati, login

Hi I am running 11.04 on a Dell Inspiron 530

Below I have pasted what hardware I have and some dmesg pasted info

**Here is the problem:**

When I log out many times I cannot seem to log back in again. It freezes without any panels appearing which I suspect is an issue with gdm?

I usually resort then to alt/print-screen and k to re-reboot and that mostly works and boots back to Unity which then works wonderfully.

I cannot understand why this does not happen when I start the pc up from scratch but only seems to happen on logout-in or sometimes reboot.

I am using only ubuntu on this pc also

Here is print out from lspci

lspci

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 82G33/G31/P35/P31 Express DRAM Controller (rev 02)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82G33/G31/P35/P31 Express PCI Express Root Port (rev 02)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82562V-2 10/100 Network Connection (rev 02)
00:1a.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 02)
00:1a.1 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #5 (rev 02)
00:1a.2 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #6 (rev 02)
00:1a.7 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #2 (rev 02)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) HD Audio Controller (rev 02)
00:1d.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 02)
00:1d.1 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 02)
00:1d.2 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 02)
00:1d.7 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1 (rev 02)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev 92)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801IR (ICH9R) LPC Interface Controller (rev 02)
00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801IR/IO/IH (ICH9R/DO/DH) 4 port SATA IDE Controller (rev 02)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) SMBus Controller (rev 02)
00:1f.5 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) 2 port SATA IDE Controller (rev 02)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: ATI Technologies Inc RV610 video device [Radeon HD 2400 PRO]
```

Here is from lsusb:

```
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 003: ID 413c:2003 Dell Computer Corp. Keyboard
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 0461:4d22 Primax Electronics, Ltd 
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 03f0:7804 Hewlett-Packard DeskJet D1360
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 046d:089d Logitech, Inc. QuickCam E2500 series
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

If it helps also here is the readout from dmesg:

```
[    5.965964] [drm]   VGA
[    5.965965] [drm]   DDC: 0x7e50 0x7e50 0x7e54 0x7e54 0x7e58 0x7e58 0x7e5c 0x7e5c
[    5.965967] [drm]   Encoders:
[    5.965968] [drm]     CRT2: INTERNAL_KLDSCP_DAC2
[    5.965969] [drm] Connector 2:
[    5.965970] [drm]   DVI-I
[    5.965971] [drm]   HPD1
[    5.965973] [drm]   DDC: 0x7e40 0x7e40 0x7e44 0x7e44 0x7e48 0x7e48 0x7e4c 0x7e4c
[    5.965974] [drm]   Encoders:
[    5.965975] [drm]     CRT1: INTERNAL_KLDSCP_DAC1
[    5.965976] [drm]     DFP1: INTERNAL_LVTM1
[    6.019898] [drm] Internal thermal controller without fan control
[    6.019952] [drm] radeon: power management initialized
[    6.098623] [drm] fb mappable at 0xD0141000
[    6.098625] [drm] vram apper at 0xD0000000
[    6.098626] [drm] size 5324800
[    6.098627] [drm] fb depth is 24
[    6.098629] [drm]    pitch is 5888
[    6.098792] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 180x56
[    6.098817] fb0: radeondrmfb frame buffer device
[    6.098818] drm: registered panic notifier
[    6.098823] [drm] Initialized radeon 2.8.0 20080528 for 0000:01:00.0 on minor 0
[    6.437588] usbcore: registered new interface driver snd-usb-audio
[    6.533185] HDA Intel 0000:00:1b.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 22 (level, low) -> IRQ 22
[    6.533222] HDA Intel 0000:00:1b.0: irq 43 for MSI/MSI-X
[    6.533242] HDA Intel 0000:00:1b.0: setting latency timer to 64
[    6.608241] type=1400 audit(1305191778.439:2): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=499 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    6.608870] type=1400 audit(1305191778.439:3): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=499 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    6.609060] type=1400 audit(1305191778.439:4): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=447 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    6.609274] type=1400 audit(1305191778.439:5): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=499 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    6.609688] type=1400 audit(1305191778.439:6): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=447 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    6.610094] type=1400 audit(1305191778.439:7): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=447 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    6.756553] input: HDA Intel Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input5
[    9.924552] usblp0: USB Bidirectional printer dev 3 if 0 alt 0 proto 2 vid 0x03F0 pid 0x7804
[    9.924903] usbcore: registered new interface driver usblp
[   12.538889] ppdev: user-space parallel port driver
[   12.876847] type=1400 audit(1305191784.707:8): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/lib/cups/backend/cups-pdf" pid=828 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   12.877582] type=1400 audit(1305191784.707:9): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=828 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   12.898935] type=1400 audit(1305191784.727:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=831 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   12.899575] type=1400 audit(1305191784.727:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=831 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   12.899975] type=1400 audit(1305191784.727:12): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=831 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   14.000492] type=1400 audit(1305191785.831:13): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/share/gdm/guest-session/Xsession" pid=830 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   14.004217] type=1400 audit(1305191785.835:14): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/lib/cups/backend/cups-pdf" pid=837 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   14.004956] type=1400 audit(1305191785.835:15): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=837 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   14.360859] type=1400 audit(1305191786.191:16): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/sbin/mysqld-akonadi" pid=838 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   14.361285] type=1400 audit(1305191786.191:17): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/sbin/mysqld-akonadi///usr/sbin/mysqld" pid=838 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   15.144178] e1000e 0000:00:19.0: irq 41 for MSI/MSI-X
[   15.200046] e1000e 0000:00:19.0: irq 41 for MSI/MSI-X
[   15.200263] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[   16.387139] usb 4-2: usbfs: interface 0 claimed by usblp while 'usb' sets config #1
[   16.668752] e1000e: eth0 NIC Link is Up 100 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: None
[   16.668757] e1000e 0000:00:19.0: eth0: 10/100 speed: disabling TSO
[   16.668889] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
[   20.584348] EXT4-fs (sda1): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro,user_xattr,commit=0
[   26.878702] EXT4-fs (sda1): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro,user_xattr,commit=0
[   27.504006] eth0: no IPv6 routers present
[   65.681147] show_signal_msg: 12 callbacks suppressed
[   65.681152] python[1732]: segfault at 1b0 ip b66c89ef sp bfa2a820 error 4 in libdbus-1.so.3.5.4[b669e000+3b000]
[   72.109525] python[1839]: segfault at 8b32002 ip b74a06bd sp b5d75928 error 4 in libc-2.13.so[b7389000+15a000]
[   74.574963] process `skype' is using obsolete setsockopt SO_BSDCOMPAT
[  440.860838] nautilus[1469]: segfault at 20 ip b6c1dfc2 sp bf8d6ba0 error 4 in libgobject-2.0.so.0.2800.6[b6beb000+45000]
[  468.597037] SysRq : SAK
[  468.597055] SAK: killed process 2320 (Xorg): task_session(p)==tty->session
[  468.597195] SAK: killed process 2320 (Xorg): task_session(p)==tty->session
[  474.533041] SysRq : SAK
[  474.533057] SAK: killed process 2531 (Xorg): task_session(p)==tty->session
[  474.533178] SAK: killed process 2531 (Xorg): task_session(p)==tty->session
[  474.980661] [drm:drm_mode_getfb] *ERROR* invalid framebuffer id
[  480.884016] radeon 0000:01:00.0: GPU lockup CP stall for more than 10052msec
[  480.884020] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[  480.884043] WARNING: at /build/buildd/linux-2.6.38/drivers/gpu/drm/radeon/radeon_fence.c:248 radeon_fence_wait+0x2ea/0x360 [radeon]()
[  480.884046] Hardware name: Inspiron 530
[  480.884049] GPU lockup (waiting for 0x0000A2A4 last fence id 0x0000A29B)
[  480.884051] Modules linked in: binfmt_misc parport_pc ppdev usblp snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec snd_usb_audio snd_pcm snd_hwdep snd_usbmidi_lib snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi snd_seq gspca_zc3xx snd_timer snd_seq_device gspca_main videodev radeon ttm drm_kms_helper psmouse serio_raw snd soundcore snd_page_alloc dcdbas drm lp i2c_algo_bit parport usbhid hid floppy e1000e
[  480.884083] Pid: 2666, comm: Xorg Not tainted 2.6.38-8-generic-pae #42-Ubuntu
[  480.884086] Call Trace:
[  480.884094]  [<c1058ce2>] ? warn_slowpath_common+0x72/0xa0
[  480.884112]  [<f88f4f3a>] ? radeon_fence_wait+0x2ea/0x360 [radeon]
[  480.884130]  [<f88f4f3a>] ? radeon_fence_wait+0x2ea/0x360 [radeon]
[  480.884134]  [<c1058db3>] ? warn_slowpath_fmt+0x33/0x40
[  480.884151]  [<f88f4f3a>] ? radeon_fence_wait+0x2ea/0x360 [radeon]
[  480.884158]  [<c1076c70>] ? autoremove_wake_function+0x0/0x50
[  480.884175]  [<f88f57c1>] ? radeon_sync_obj_wait+0x11/0x20 [radeon]
[  480.884184]  [<f84ae719>] ? ttm_bo_wait+0xd9/0x170 [ttm]
[  480.884204]  [<f890d8c2>] ? radeon_gem_wait_idle_ioctl+0x82/0xe0 [radeon]
[  480.884218]  [<f8788db1>] ? drm_ioctl+0x1e1/0x470 [drm]
[  480.884241]  [<f890d840>] ? radeon_gem_wait_idle_ioctl+0x0/0xe0 [radeon]
[  480.884247]  [<c1013b00>] ? restore_i387_xstate+0xf0/0x210
[  480.884251]  [<c113251c>] ? rw_verify_area+0x6c/0x130
[  480.884262]  [<f8788bd0>] ? drm_ioctl+0x0/0x470 [drm]
[  480.884267]  [<c1141ecb>] ? do_vfs_ioctl+0x7b/0x2e0
[  480.884270]  [<c1009cde>] ? restore_sigcontext+0xbe/0xe0
[  480.884274]  [<c11421b7>] ? sys_ioctl+0x87/0x90
[  480.884277]  [<c100ab5f>] ? sysenter_do_call+0x12/0x28
[  480.884280] ---[ end trace 448eaf87bbc222a1 ]---
[  480.884287] [drm] Disabling audio support
[  480.885369] radeon 0000:01:00.0: GPU softreset 
[  480.885372] radeon 0000:01:00.0:   R_008010_GRBM_STATUS=0xE57024E0
[  480.885375] radeon 0000:01:00.0:   R_008014_GRBM_STATUS2=0x00110103
[  480.885378] radeon 0000:01:00.0:   R_000E50_SRBM_STATUS=0x200000C0
[  480.885385] radeon 0000:01:00.0:   R_008020_GRBM_SOFT_RESET=0x00007FEE
[  480.900270] radeon 0000:01:00.0: R_008020_GRBM_SOFT_RESET=0x00000001
[  480.916147] radeon 0000:01:00.0:   R_008010_GRBM_STATUS=0xA0003030
[  480.916149] radeon 0000:01:00.0:   R_008014_GRBM_STATUS2=0x00000003
[  480.916152] radeon 0000:01:00.0:   R_000E50_SRBM_STATUS=0x200080C0
[  480.917146] radeon 0000:01:00.0: GPU reset succeed
[  480.920500] radeon 0000:01:00.0: WB enabled
[  480.951456] [drm] ring test succeeded in 1 usecs
[  480.951462] [drm] ib test succeeded in 1 usecs
[  480.951463] [drm] Enabling audio support
[  640.045683] nautilus[2821]: segfault at 20 ip b6b87fc2 sp bfe51e40 error 4 in libgobject-2.0.so.0.2800.6[b6b55000+45000]
[  662.069107] SysRq : SAK
[  662.069139] SAK: killed process 3405 (Xorg): task_session(p)==tty->session
[  662.069301] SAK: killed process 3405 (Xorg): task_session(p)==tty->session
[  662.737841] [drm:drm_mode_getfb] *ERROR* invalid framebuffer id
[  663.636017] radeon 0000:01:00.0: GPU lockup CP stall for more than 10052msec
[  663.636021] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[  663.636045] WARNING: at /build/buildd/linux-2.6.38/drivers/gpu/drm/radeon/radeon_fence.c:248 radeon_fence_wait+0x2ea/0x360 [radeon]()
[  663.636048] Hardware name: Inspiron 530
[  663.636050] GPU lockup (waiting for 0x0000C703 last fence id 0x0000C702)
[  663.636052] Modules linked in: binfmt_misc parport_pc ppdev usblp snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec snd_usb_audio snd_pcm snd_hwdep snd_usbmidi_lib snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi snd_seq gspca_zc3xx snd_timer snd_seq_device gspca_main videodev radeon ttm drm_kms_helper psmouse serio_raw snd soundcore snd_page_alloc dcdbas drm lp i2c_algo_bit parport usbhid hid floppy e1000e
[  663.636086] Pid: 3551, comm: compiz Tainted: G        W   2.6.38-8-generic-pae #42-Ubuntu
[  663.636088] Call Trace:
[  663.636097]  [<c1058ce2>] ? warn_slowpath_common+0x72/0xa0
[  663.636114]  [<f88f4f3a>] ? radeon_fence_wait+0x2ea/0x360 [radeon]
[  663.636132]  [<f88f4f3a>] ? radeon_fence_wait+0x2ea/0x360 [radeon]
[  663.636136]  [<c1058db3>] ? warn_slowpath_fmt+0x33/0x40
[  663.636154]  [<f88f4f3a>] ? radeon_fence_wait+0x2ea/0x360 [radeon]
[  663.636161]  [<c1076c70>] ? autoremove_wake_function+0x0/0x50
[  663.636178]  [<f88f57c1>] ? radeon_sync_obj_wait+0x11/0x20 [radeon]
[  663.636187]  [<f84ae719>] ? ttm_bo_wait+0xd9/0x170 [ttm]
[  663.636210]  [<f890d8c2>] ? radeon_gem_wait_idle_ioctl+0x82/0xe0 [radeon]
[  663.636220]  [<f8788db1>] ? drm_ioctl+0x1e1/0x470 [drm]
[  663.636236]  [<f890d840>] ? radeon_gem_wait_idle_ioctl+0x0/0xe0 [radeon]
[  663.636241]  [<c110bd79>] ? handle_mm_fault+0x109/0x190
[  663.636244]  [<c1534fb0>] ? do_page_fault+0x0/0x490
[  663.636246]  [<c15351df>] ? do_page_fault+0x22f/0x490
[  663.636254]  [<f8788bd0>] ? drm_ioctl+0x0/0x470 [drm]
[  663.636257]  [<c1141ecb>] ? do_vfs_ioctl+0x7b/0x2e0
[  663.636259]  [<c11421b7>] ? sys_ioctl+0x87/0x90
[  663.636262]  [<c100ab5f>] ? sysenter_do_call+0x12/0x28
[  663.636264] ---[ end trace 448eaf87bbc222a2 ]---
[  663.636272] [drm] Disabling audio support
[  663.637335] radeon 0000:01:00.0: GPU softreset 
[  663.637337] radeon 0000:01:00.0:   R_008010_GRBM_STATUS=0xE57024E0
[  663.637340] radeon 0000:01:00.0:   R_008014_GRBM_STATUS2=0x00110103
[  663.637342] radeon 0000:01:00.0:   R_000E50_SRBM_STATUS=0x200010C0
[  663.637350] radeon 0000:01:00.0:   R_008020_GRBM_SOFT_RESET=0x00007FEE
[  663.652234] radeon 0000:01:00.0: R_008020_GRBM_SOFT_RESET=0x00000001
[  663.668109] radeon 0000:01:00.0:   R_008010_GRBM_STATUS=0xA0003030
[  663.668111] radeon 0000:01:00.0:   R_008014_GRBM_STATUS2=0x00000003
[  663.668113] radeon 0000:01:00.0:   R_000E50_SRBM_STATUS=0x200080C0
[  663.669107] radeon 0000:01:00.0: GPU reset succeed
[  663.672556] radeon 0000:01:00.0: WB enabled
[  663.703517] [drm] ring test succeeded in 1 usecs
[  663.703524] [drm] ib test succeeded in 1 usecs
[  663.703527] [drm] Enabling audio support
```

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I think I found the answer the wrong way though!

I had to mess around with my video driver for the ATI Radeon card so tried ...much against my wishes to install fglrx...last time I did this ..it broke. However I did 
sudo apt-get install fglrx and then after that had finished installing and configuring xorg etc I rebooted fine and dandy and kept on rebooting with no stalling so maybe I have fixed it after all.

Can I mark this as solved now?